# @Html.DropDownListFor fails in partial view but not in Full Page View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ienumerable, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am having an issue where my PartialView DropDownListFor gets the error:

```
The ViewData item that has the key PlanId is of type System.int32 but must be of type   
IEnumerable<SelectListItem>

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.PlanId, (SelectList)ViewBar.PlanNameSelectList, new {@class = "short" })
```

This error does not pop up when I go to the page that originally held this code. What I have done is gutted the core part of the code which has worked previously with another partialView, as long as I took out the DropDownListFor elements in the code. I did not need them for that partialView, but now that I need them the problem has come full circle.

I would greatly appreciate any help that can be given to me to help solve this problem. Other resources like calls to the partial are below

```
@Html.Partial("location", new MAO.Models.ViewModels.CreateTemplateModel{})
```

This is the model

```
public class CreateTemplateModel {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [RegularExpression("^[0-9]+$", ErrorMessage="Template Id can only contain numbers")]
    [Display(Name = "Template ID")]
    public string TNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    [RegularExpression("^.[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{3})?$", ErrorMessage = "H# Must follow either @XXXX or @XXXX-XXX pattern")]
    [Display(Name = "HNumber")]
    public string HNumber { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfOtherIsEmpty("NewPlanName", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Plan Name")]
    [Display(Name = "Select Existing Plan Name")]
    public int PlanId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage="{0} can't be longer than 500 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter New Plan Name")]
    public string NewPlanName { get; set; }

    [RequiredIfOtherIsEmpty("NewParentOrganization", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Parent Organization")]
    [Display(Name = "Select Existing Parent Organization")]
    public string ParentOrganization { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(500, ErrorMessage = "{0} can't be longer than 500 characters")]
    [Display(Name = "Enter New Parent Organization")]
    public string NewParentOrganization { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is required.")]
    public int TemplateTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

There is a controller that is pretty long so I am not going to post that. If there are parts of the controller that would be helpful I can post those parts as well as anything else that I might have forgotten to include

Comment: Is there a difference in the strongly-typed models for both the view and partial view?

Comment: I just started working in all of this and have 0 classical training on it so to be honest I don't even know what strongly typed means in reference to C# and models.

Comment: No problem!  A strongly-typed view means that a model is bound to it.  If your view is strongly-typed, you'll see a model declaration at the top that looks something like @model MAO.Models.ViewModels.CreateTemplateModel.  As an aside, when you're rendering your partial you're creating a new model.  Is anything ever saturating that model?

Comment: To answer first part. Yes this is a strongly typed model. I am not sure what the saturation means. If it means that a model is linked to two pages than yes. I have a partial that i gutted the code out of to keep the integrity of the original page.

Comment: The model is linking the two but it is just an empty model correct?  Does anything fill it?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. I create an empty instance and it looks like Create is called in the controller that than calls attachSelectLists(ViewBag) to fill and attach the list to be called and displayed in the partial view.

    [CustomAuthorizeAttribute(Roles = UserRole.MANAGER)]
        public ActionResult Create() {
            attachSelectLists(ViewBag);

            return View();
        }

ViewBag.PlanNameSelectList = new SelectList(plans.Distinct(), "Id", "Name", plans.FirstOrDefault(plan => plan.Name == selectedPlan));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm suspecting that you're never rebinding your drop down list when you are returning your partial view.  Your controller action for the partial should be building your dropdown list in an identical manner to the controller action that renders the full view.  Compare the two and make sure that they match.

UPDATE:  Your partial view action should look something like the following:

```
public ActionResult Location()
{
    ViewBag.PlanNameSelectList = new SelectList(plans.Distinct(), "Id", "Name", plans.FirstOrDefault(plan => plan.Name == selectedPlan));
    attachSelectLists(ViewBag); 
    return PartialView("Location");
}
```

What you are currently doing with

```
@Html.Partial("location", new MAO.Models.ViewModels.CreateTemplateModel{})
```

Is rendering the partial view "location" using a NEW CreateTemplateModel object, not an existing one.  Instead, a better way to do it is to duplicate your controller actions.  Create a new one specifically for your partial view (this is a simpler use case for now).

```
public ActonResult TestPartialView()
```

Instead of using @Html.Partial which renders a partial, try calling your new controller action instead, which will build your drop down list for you.

```
@Html.RenderAction("TestPartialView").
```

This will call your new controller action and render the partial on the page, preserving the controller logic.  If you use @Html.Partial, it simply renders the partial view passing in whatever object you give it which, in this case, is a new, empty CreateTemplateModel.

Comment: So I would need a whole new separate controller for the partial view and not have both partialview and regview connected to the same controller?

Comment: You could of course.  You could render them both in the same controller depending on some logic flow.  However, if they aren't returning identical data, they need separate returns and you don't want to be using return View() to return a partial view.

Comment: I do have identical data being returned. I wish I understood what the backend was doing so that I could not come off as a dumb dumb right now. I have a public ActionResult Create(){attachSelectList(ViewBag); return View();} This I know is automatically called when the page is loaded, or I at least assume it is called when the page is loaded/called. How would I get the partialView not to fail with the selectlist having the controlled work for both. Should I create another method, but overload it so that it passes a value to distinguish between the two?

Comment: The Create in the controller is not reached for the partialView. This method is reached if I go to the page I gutted it from. Do you know why that would happen?

Comment: If you create a new controller action for your partial view, it would never hit Create().  It would instead hit your new controller action.  In my example, it would be TestPartialView()

Comment: This is true. I found what you were talking about and you are completely correct. I put the attachSelectLists(ViewBag) in the index method just to test and it loaded which means exactly what you were saying. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @Rob Perfect!  So glad that you got it to work!  Best of luck.